# Why does cin.fail() ignore periods and commas in "while" loop? What's a simple way to error check input?

Tags: c++, cin

Sorry it sounds stupid, but I'm just getting started in C++ programming...
My input checking loop works fine if I want it to accept 'float' numbers, but outputs some weird results if it has to accept only 'int' numbers.
**EDIT:** Tutorials I read/watched assumed that user wouldn't input things like that, which is dumb...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

// input with check
int num(int i) {
    int x=0;
    cout<<"Enter #"<<i+1<<": ";
    cin>>x;
    while(cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout<<"Enter INTEGER #"<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>x;
    }
    return x;
}

int main() 
{
    int i, min=0, max=0, n=3;
    int arr[3];

    // save input into array
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) { arr[i] = num(i); }
    
    // find 'max' & 'min'
    max = arr[0];
    for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if(max < arr[i]) { max = arr[i]; }
    }
    min = arr[0];
    for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if(min > arr[i]) { min = arr[i]; }
    }
    cout << endl << "MAX = " << max;
    cout << endl << "MIN = " << min;
    return 0;
}
```

For example if I type in **5.2** it takes in the **5**, skips one loop and puts out error message on the next loop.

**Output:**

*Enter #1: 2*

*Enter #2: 5.5*

*Enter #3: Enter INTEGER #3: g*

*Enter INTEGER #3: -2*

*MAX = 5*

*MIN = -2*

**EDIT2:** I did some digging and I found something that kind of works for my use and is simple enough for my skill level, but still has some quirks. Function just filters out anything that isn't characters you specify between the quotes and checks if '-' is as the first character.

```
bool isNumeric(string const &str) {
    if(str.find_last_of("-")==0 || str.find_last_of("-")==SIZE_MAX) {
        return !str.empty() && str.find_first_not_of("-0123456789") == string::npos;
    } else { return 0; }
}
int num(int i) {
    string str;
    cout << "Enter #" << i+1 << ": ";
    getline(cin,str);
    while(isNumeric(str)==0) {
        cout << "Enter INTEGER #" << i+1 << ": ";
        getline(cin,str);
    }
    return stoi(str); // convert string to integer
}
```

Source: https://www.techiedelight.com/determine-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-cpp/ - method #3

Comment: `int x; std::cin >> x;` will consume from a stream only characters that form an integer. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt . If you enter "5.5", then it eats the first 5, leaving ".5" in the input buffer, which triggers the error message from the next loop.

Comment: Haphazard calls to `clear()` and `ignore()` are symptomatic of random attempts to fix input parsing without fully understand what the original problem is, and the proper way to fix it. Instead the correct approach would be to understand how formatted extraction operator works, and the proper ways to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cin read '5'-> integer -> get -> cin read '.' -> not integer -> not get -> n = 5 -> recall func -> cin read '.' -> not integer -> invalid -> cin fail

if you write like this:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
double b;
cin >> b;
cout << a << "   " << b;
```

with input 5.5, the output will be 5   0.5.
If you want check if your input is integer, you can write like this:

```
bool isInteger(char* s, int length) {
    if (length == 0) return false;
    if (s[0] != '-' && s[0] != '+' && !isdigit(s[0])) return false;
    for (int i = 1; i < length;)  if (!isdigit(s[i++])) return false;
    return true;
}

int num(int i) {
    char c[11];
    cout << "Enter #" << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin.getline(c, 11);
    while (!isInteger(c, cin.gcount() - 1)) {
        cout << "Enter INTEGER #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(c, 11);
    }
    return stoi(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that cin.fail() would have things like that built in... but this works for me too.

Comment: Now that I've tested it, your code works for "5.1" "5,1" and non-numbers, but it still lets through spaces, which is not ideal.

Comment: @Charles-S ok, code edited

Comment: Sorry, but 1. I think instead of 'x' there supposed to be 'c'? 2. it now is in an infinite loop...

Comment: @Charles-S sorry about that, I edited by my phone so I didn't check it, it should be cin.gcount() - 1, not cin.gcount()